# Bash, Same variable being used in recursion

Tags: arrays, linux, bash, recursion, directory

A problem I'm working on for Uni is to move through a directory and count all files and directories plus those in the subdirectories. I cannot use the commands find, locate, du or any recursive commands such as ls -R. To solve this I'm creating my own recursive command. I've run into the problem where the same array is being used in each recursion, now with something like java a recursion would allocate each variable in the recursion with a different id. But here the same variable is being used. I can tell this from my output where it's printing out directories from a super-directory rather than the current directory being used. The hierarchy in use is [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R8SYV.png) and the output I've got is [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O6wCW.png)

```
tgtdir=$1
visfiles=0
hidfiles=0
visdir=0
hiddir=0
function searchDirectory {
    curdir=$1

    echo "curdir = $curdir" 
    # Rather than change directory ensure that each recursive call uses the $curdir/NameOfWantedDirectory
    noDir=$(ls -l -A $curdir| grep ^d | wc -l) # Work out the number of directories in the current directory
    echo "noDir = $noDir"

    shopt -s nullglob # Enable nullglob to prevent a null term being added to the array

    y=0 # Declares a variable to act as a index value
    for i in $( ls -d ${curdir}*/ ${curdir}.*/ ); do # loops through all directories both visible and hidden
        if [[ "${i:(-3)}" = "../" ]]; then
            echo "Found ../"
            continue;
        elif [[ "${i:(-2)}" = "./" ]]; then
            echo "Found ./"
            continue;
        else # When position i is ./ or ../ the loop advances otherwise the value is added to directories and y is incremented before the loop advances
            echo "Adding $i to directories"
            directories[y]="$i"
            let "y++"
        fi
    done # Adds all directories except ./ and ../ to the array directories
    shopt -u nullglob #Turn off nullglob to ensure it doesn't later interfere
    echo "${directories[@]}"
    if [[ "${noDir}" -gt "0" ]]; then
        for i in "${directories[@]}"; do
            searchDirectory $i
        done # Loops through subdirectories to reach the bottom of the hierarchy using recursion
    fi

    visfiles=$(ls -l $tgtdir | grep -v ^total | grep -v ^d | wc -l)
    # Calls the ls -l command which puts each file on a new line, then removes the line which states the total and any lines starting with a 'd' which would be a directory with grep -v,
    #finally counts all lines using wc -l
    hiddenfiles=$(expr $(ls -l -a $tgtdir | grep -v ^total | grep -v ^d | wc -l) - $visfiles) 
    # Finds the total number of files including hidden and puts them on a line each (using -l and -a (all)) removes the line stating the total as well as any directoriesand then counts them. 
    #Then stores the number of hidden files by expressing the complete number of files minus the visible files.
    visdir=$(ls -l $tgtdir | grep ^d | wc -l)
    # Counts visible directories by using ls -l then filtering it with grep to find all lines starting with a d indicating a directory. Then counts the lines with wc -l.
    hiddir=$(expr $(ls -l -a $tgtdir | grep ^d | wc -l) - $visdir)
    # Finds hidden directories by expressing total number of directories including hidden - total number of visible directories
    #At minimum this will be 2 as it includes the directories . and ..
    echo "Increased Values"
}
searchDirectory $tgtdir
echo "Total Files: $visfiles (+$hiddenfiles hidden)"
echo "Directories Found: $visdir (+$hiddir hidden)"
echo "Total files and directories: $total"
exit 0
```

Comment: If you're using bash, the `local` keyword is your friend here I think.

Comment: Declare your locals!

Comment: Also, **seriously**, you couldn't build a 3-line reproducer? This is far, *far* more code than the question calls for; see http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve.

Comment: Agreed, it's nice to see some code and you've clearly made an attempt at solving your problem but it's a lot easier for us to help you if we're not distracted by everything else going on in your code.

Comment: BTW, there are other bugs in your original question which http://shellcheck.net/ would find automatically.

Comment: Also, don't **ever** use `ls` programatically. `dirs=( "$curdir"/*/ ); noDir=${#dirs[@]}` is both more efficient and more correct. See http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs

Comment: Similarly, `for i in $( ls -d ${curdir}*/ ${curdir}.*/ ); do` generates bugs when you have directories with wildcards or whitespace in their names, which simultaneously being wildly inefficient compared to `for i in "$curdir"/*/ "$curdir"/.*/; do` (which I'd also call ill-advised; there are better ways to tell the shell to include hidden directories in glob results)

Comment: ...and, well, why in the world wouldn't you just use `find`? Unlike `ls`, it supports `-print0`, and so can emit output in a manner that can be unambiguously parsed even when filenames contain whitespace/newlines/etc. See also http://mywiki.wooledge.org/UsingFind -- and, for parsing NUL-delimited streams such as those emitted by `find -print0`, there's a comment in BashFAQ #1 (http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001).

Comment: (Also, using `expr` for math is outright antiquated; for any shell compliant with POSIX sh -- standardized in the early 90s -- C-style math syntax is available inside `$(( ))` expansions).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [this](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/localvar.html), you should declare `directories` as local variable using `local`. If ommited, the variable will be global. Give it a try.

Comment: Not just `directories` -- but `curdir`, `noDir`, `i`, and every other variable.

Comment: BTW, I strongly suggest that you avoid suggesting the ABS as a reference; while it does have a great deal of Google juice, it often uses bad practices in its examples; those of us who spend time in freenode's #bash channel are often saddled with helping people unlearn bad practices they picked up there.

Comment: Cheers, this sorted the problem

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Woah, good to know that. I'll keep that in mind, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Consider a simpler reproducer:

```
foo() {
  var=$1
  (( var > 10 )) && return
  foo "$(( $var * 2 ))"
  echo "Passed $var"
}

( foo 1 )
```

Because all variables in shell are global unless explicitly declared otherwise, with simply `var=$1`, this will emit:

```
Passed 16
Passed 16
Passed 16
Passed 16
```

With `local var` or `declare var`, this will correctly emit:

```
Passed 8
Passed 4
Passed 2
Passed 1
```